# Captcha characters not showing IIS 10 PHP version greater than 7.0.30

Tags: php, iis, captcha

I have IIS, version 10.0.18362.1, installed on my local machine and have updated the PHP version to version 7.4.4.  I noticed captcha PHP script is only showing the background image and not the characters. However, when I change the PHP version to 7.0.30, the characters are visible.

I know that to display the characters, gd support is required.  I confirmed that gd support is enabled for version 7.4.4.   Looking over phpinfo for version 7.0.30 and 7.4.4, the only differences are:

version 7.0.30

- FreeType version 2.8.1

version 7.4.4

- FreeType version 2.9.1
- Has two extra fields; BMP Support and TGA Read Support.  Both are enabled.

I greatly appreciated any assistance with displaying captcha characters for PHP version set higher than 7.0.30 using IIS version 10.0.18362.1 as the localhost server.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could try to Enable 32-bit application for your website in IIS manager->application pool->advanced setting->change Enable 32-bit application from false to true.
you may need to check whether the static content feature has been enabled in turn windows features on or off.

Comment: I tried your suggestions.  32-bit application was originally false for me and I had static content enabled. Unfortunately enabling the 32-bit application feature did not work in my case.

Comment: Jalpa,

Thanks for your reply.   I am using  EasyCaptcha -http://kestas.kuliukas.com/EasyCaptcha/ - and have followed the instructions to implement onto a web page.

See screenshot - http://ronancorr.com/captcha-image.jpg

I also tried using a different captcha code - https://github.com/Serubin/Simple-PHP-Captcha - and got the same results - the background is there, but the text doesn't display.

I also visited php.net - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php - to learn more about GD image text.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

https://www.php.net/manual/tr/function.imagettftext.php

putenv('GDFONTPATH=' . realpath('.'));

// Font type (.ttf not use)

$file = 'filename';

imagettftext($image, 20, 0, 10, 20, $siyah, $file, $text);